# Expectation of the Sum of K Numbers

Tags: algorithm, statistics, histogram, probability

I am working on a histogram problem, and then I ran into the following math problem:

Given N numbers, where the value of each number is different, denoted as v1, v2, ..., vn, and the probability of selecting each number is p1, p2, ..., pn, respectively.

Now if I select K numbers based on the given probabilities, where K <= N, what is the expectation of the sum of those K numbers? Note that the selection is without replacement, so that the K numbers cannot involve duplicate numbers. I understand that if the selection is with replacement, the expectation of the sum of the K numbers equals K * E(V), where E(V) = v1*p1 + v2*p2 + ... + vn*p2.

Furthermore, what about the expectation of the variance of those K numbers?

This question is better formulated at [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80949/expectation-of-the-sum-of-k-numbers?noredirect=1#comment158632_80949).

Comment: This is probably a better question for math.stackexchange.com as it doesn't really involve coding. Interesting question though - unequal probabilities, but no replacement...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics, not programming

Comment: Please take a look at the answer given here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12258/expectation-of-the-variance-of-the-sampling-set-without-replacement